# Errors export java project into a jar

Tags: java, jar

I've got a question that I can't understand why eclipse make this. I've got a method inside a java class called `Cliente`. Everything goes well, however when I export the jar I see the code with a decompiler and I can't understand why this method isn't ok. Some code from my method:

```
 public RespuestaEnvio enviar(Envio mensaje){
    log.info(modulo, "Preparando el envío del mensaje: "+mensaje.getMensaje());
            String mensajeError = "";
            boolean descartar = false;
            BeanCambioSituacion beanCambioSituacion = new BeanCambioSituacion(mensaje);
            // Se validan campos obligatorios
            if(isVacia(beanCambioSituacion.getCodigoPedido())){
                log.error(modulo, "Código de pedido sin valor.");
                descartar = true;
            } 

            if(isVacia(beanCambioSituacion.getNumeroEnvio())){
                log.error(modulo, "Número de envío sin valor.");
                descartar = true;
            }

This method with a decompiler seeing the code:

/* Error */
  public gestionEventos.RespuestaEnvio enviar(gestionEventos.Envio mensaje)
  {


// Byte code:
//   0: aload_0
//   1: getfield 49 es/chx/ws/eci/cambiaEstado/Cliente:log  Les/chx/ws/eci/domain/LogUtil;
//   4: aload_0
//   5: getfield 41 es/chx/ws/eci/cambiaEstado/Cliente:modulo   Ljava/lang/String;
//   8: new 116 java/lang/StringBuilder
//   11: dup
//   12: ldc -15
//   14: invokespecial 120  java/lang/StringBuilder:<init>  (Ljava/lang/String;)V
//   17: aload_1
//   18: invokevirtual 243  gestionEventos/Envio:getMensaje ()Ljava/lang/String;
//   21: invokevirtual 121  java/lang/StringBuilder:append  (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
//   24: invokevirtual 131  java/lang/StringBuilder:toString    ()Ljava/lang/String;
//   27: invokevirtual 134  es/chx/ws/eci/domain/LogUtil:info   (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
//   30: ldc -114
//   32: astore_2
//   33: iconst_0
//   34: istore_3
//   35: new 248    es/chx/ws/eci/bean/BeanCambioSituacion
//   38: dup
//   39: aload_1
//   40: invokespecial 250  es/chx/ws/eci/bean/BeanCambioSituacion:<init>   (LgestionEventos/Envio;)V
//   43: astore 4
//   45: aload_0
//   46: aload 4
//   48: invokevirtual 253  es/chx/ws/eci/bean/BeanCambioSituacion:getCodigoPedido  ()Ljava/lang/String;
//   51: invokevirtual 256  es/chx/ws/eci/cambiaEstado/Cliente:isVacia  (Ljava/lang/String;)Z
//   54: ifeq +19 -> 73
//   57: aload_0.
```

Anyone can give some info, I can't understand why this happens. The code is completely different. This is my question. Why when I export the java project, the code is different inside the method?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to properly indent your output by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. I also fixed some minor grammar mistakes. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Well this is how java works :)

You write your the code using the java language. You (or eclipse) compiles that code with a java compiler (javac) and it will produce jvm-bytecode. The bytecode is used as the input for the java-virtual-machine (jvm) which is able to interpret and execute it.

When you open the compiled and bundled jar you'll see the bytecode.
With some fantasy/knowledge you can actually see that it is still your code:

For example:

- log something

  ```
  /domain/LogUtil;
  4: aload_0
  5: getfield 41 es/chx/ws/eci/cambiaEstado/Cliente:modulo   Ljava/lang/String;
  ```
- Combine your Log message and the the output of mensaje.getMensaje()

  ```
  8: new 116 java/lang/StringBuilder
  11: dup
  12: ldc -15
  14: invokespecial 120  java/lang/StringBuilder:<init>  (Ljava/lang/String;)V
  17: aload_1
  18: invokevirtual 243  gestionEventos/Envio:getMensaje ()Ljava/lang/String;
  21: invokevirtual 121  java/lang/StringBuilder:append  (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
  24: invokevirtual 131  java/lang/StringBuilder:toString    ()Ljava/lang/String;
  27: invokevirtual 134  es/chx/ws/eci/domain/LogUtil:info   (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
  ...
  ```
- new BeanCambioSituacion(mensaje)

  ```
  35: new 248    es/chx/ws/eci/bean/BeanCambioSituacion
  ...
  ```

You state that you opened the jar with a decompiler. As you see the
bytecode I doubt that your decompiler is setup correctly.
Decompilers like like jad (and the jadclipse plugin for eclipse) generate java code from bytecode. It is very likely that you won't get the same java code that was used for compilation because of compile-time optimizations and the fact that different java programs can produce the same bytecode.